# Using protoc-gen-go creates a .pb.go that imports google/golang but can't find package

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm using [protoc-gen-go](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated) to compile `C` `Protocol Buffers` into `Golang` which works great and I can almost `go install` the package but I get this error:

`cannot find package "google/protobuf"`

but I cannot find this package anywhere to download, can anybody tell me what I should do with this? Thanks.

I'm following all steps to doing it from [here](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)

then I run `protoc --go_out=. *.proto` and I get all my files, but the wrong `proto` import

Comment: are you running this command? `go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`... maybe could you clarify your steps.

Answer (score 1):

as @poopoothegoriall said, please use the protobuf from github, other than code-google. the generated .pb.go file will import `"github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"`

**UPDATE**
this is my steps:

1. `make install` project https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
2. `go get` https://github.com/golang/protobuf
3. generate the go source by `protoc --go_out=. xxx.proto`

Comment: I am using that, but when it compiles it includes "google/protobuf" instead of the golang version

Comment: That is exactly what I did but I still get `import _ "google/protobuf"`

Comment: https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/tree/master/Resources/Protobufs/csgo is what I'm compiling

Comment: i don't know why same steps  lead to different result. my generated go file import the github version package `import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"`. i tried your proto file, it give me error ` No syntax specified for the proto file. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";'`. if you got generation without this error, we must not in same protobuf version, and some mistake you have had.

Comment: @Jiang YD hmmm... that is interesting that you got an error. I was under the impression that proto2 did not need to be explicitly stated... unless proto changed something recently (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3 check the first bullet under defining a message). - Datsik, Could you show us one of your compiled files?

Comment: [Pick your choice](https://github.com/Gacnt/cs-go/tree/master/protos) The only thing is I manually removed the `import "google/golang"` from the top so that my program would compile properly, along with removing the import I had to remove 2 small functions that weren't anything major, I would just like this to compile without me having to remove stuff. Thanks.