# Cannot find package "google/protobuf"

Tags: go, build, blockchain, protocol-buffers

I am compiling an open source project written in go (openblockchain). I get the following error when I do `go build`. Can anyone help me with this issue

**Compilation Error**

```
> go build
../go/src/github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer/openchain/util/utils.go:28:2: cannot find package "google/protobuf" in any of:
    /usr/src/pkg/google/protobuf (from $GOROOT)
    /home/vichu/go/src/google/protobuf (from $GOPATH)
```

**Additional Information**

I referred the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930028/using-protoc-gen-go-creates-a-pb-go-that-imports-google-golang-but-cant-find-p) in Stack Overflow but still no luck in solving the issue. Here is some more information about what all I have:

Protoc version is up to date.

```
> protoc --version 
libprotoc 3.0.0
```

My environment variables

```
> echo $GOPATH
/home/vichu/go
> echo $GOBIN
/home/vichu/go/bin
```

Protobuf has been built using the README.

```
~/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf$ ls
AUTHORS  CONTRIBUTORS  jsonpb  LICENSE  Makefile  Make.protobuf  proto  protoc-gen-go  proto.pb.go  ptypes  README.md
```

**Update**

I did the following `Util.go` in source code as mentioned in answer.
The source code is open source and here is the [link](https://github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer/blob/master/openchain/util/utils.go)

```
-       gp "google/protobuf"
+       gp "github.com/google/protobuf"
```

When I do `go get`, the below is the error

```
> go get github.com/google/protobuf
can't load package: package github.com/google/protobuf: no buildable Go source files in /home/vichu/go/src/github.com/google/protobuf
```

Comment: so you are sure by importing the package using `import github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` does not help as suggested in the link you gave? why you insist using `google/protobuf`?

Comment: Post your Go code of how you are importing it.  It is quite obvious in the error messages that you are importing `googlr/protobuf`, which is wrong. It has to be `import "github.com/GoLang/protobuf/proto" `

Comment: Updated. Please take a look

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your import is wrong, you are trying to import a C++ package, not a golang package. It needs to be:

```
import ("github.com/golang/protobuf/proto")
```

If you don't have this package installed already, you need to run from command line:

```
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
```

Comment: I edited my source code to have the import as mentioned. I get this similar error when I do the 'go get'.  "can't load package: package github.com/google/protobuf: no buildable Go source files in /home/vichu/go/src/github.com/google/protobuf"

Comment: github.com/google/protobuf: isn't a go package, its C++, they are hosted at  https://github.com/golang/protobuf. Try go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto and go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go

Comment: So, why the google changed the src link to `go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go` that is not working for me? The same error occur if I use this src. However, your solution has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think,  at the end of your *.pb.go file you also do not have some thing like "gzipped FileDescriptorProto
    0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00 ...."

The issue is we use a wrong compiler for generating.

So:

1) I reinstall protobuf from: 
     https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases

2) Then (I'm using ubuntu and it has a proto compiler also):
     apt remove protobuf-compiler

Rebuild the *.proto file. It fixed the bug.