# Dataflow with Go SDK failing with 'InvalidProtocolBufferException'

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We were previously running Beam 2.11.0 which started failing due to an apparent change in URN format. When I attempted to update and use the latest release (2.13.0) the pipeline started timing out, and the only seemingly relevant error that I could identify from the logs during testing was:

`org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p13p1.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field. This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.`

To further test this, I attempted to use the wordcount example as provided in the Beam docs/repo here - https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/ - But I got the same result. I'm not sure if this is a generic error or something to do with Dataflow. The pipelines seem to work when running via direct runner.

Note: I have rebuilt our worker_harness_container_image with the latest version.

I understand the Go SDK is not officially supported by Dataflow, but could anybody tell me if the error is something related to Dataflow or some other issue?

PS: I've asked the question in Dataflow and Beam Slack channels but haven't had any response.

Comment: This does look like a mismatch between the worker and sdk. Do you have a full traceback? As well as rebuilding the worker image, you may also have to regenerate the go proto files (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9488352398ec95983b1d878f5d1df56821f9045e/sdks/go/pkg/beam/model/gen.go I think).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @robertwb - I think I see the problem. However when I regenerate, I run into another problem which is essentially the same as this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930028/using-protoc-gen-go-creates-a-pb-go-that-imports-google-golang-but-cant-find-p?lq=1 - The generated proto file tries to import "google/protobuf" - I'm not sure if this is an issue with my local setup but I can't see to work around it.

Comment: @robertwb PS should the proto files in the repo be updated? The src is proto3 (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/model/pipeline/src/main/proto/beam_runner_api.proto) but the generated are proto2 (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/model/pipeline_v1/beam_runner_api.pb.go) - unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, I think the proto files in the repo need to be updated as well. I'll ping someone who knows more about Go about how to do this.

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/model/PROTOBUF.md

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue using v2.13.0. Any consistent way worked out to make this work?

Comment: @buckaroo1177125 I didn't get it working I've had to put it on hold for now. I'm pretty sure its the protobuf files that need to be updated in the repo and there are instructions on how to do it I just couldn't get it working. Did you try?

Comment: @Tim I did manage to do that but it didn't change the outcome. I've detailed my attempts in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016340/apache-beam-go-sdk-with-dataflow/57189138).